# WinRT GridView ItemContainerGenerator doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

I have an issue with snapped view Win8 application. I have two grids defined in XAML and just switch their visibility on changing visual state. Each of them contents a GridView with the same items source and template:

```xml
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TagTemplate">
        <Viewbox Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewportHeightConverter}, ConverterParameter=2.3}" Margin="0,0,20,10">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Icon}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Icon property of DataContext is a Canvas element loaded from XAML file in assets (it is a picture converted from SVG). When I load this page it looks right, but when I switch its visual state tags disappear. Using `XAMLSpy` tool I've found that DataContext of ContentPresenter inside this template is correct, bu Content is null. Also when I invoke ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem() in code-behind it always returns `null`. The ItemsPanel for both GridViews are WinRTXamlToolkit WrapPanels. Can anyone help me where is my mistake or point me a way to invalidate gridview? I've tried to call InvalidateArrange() and UpdateLayout() but they didn't help.